# Changes to the scope of an API endpoint are not taken into account unless restarting WSO2. Product bug? If not, any way to configure this behaviour?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Starting with an API defined in WSO2 with no scopes associated to its endpoints...

[image]

... I get an access token and invoke them correctly.

Now I modify and publish my API, assigning a scope to one on the endpoints so that it requires the editor scope:

[image]

Now I invoke that editor scoped endpoint with the previous access_token and it works. **This shouldn't happen** since the token was given with the default scope, not the editor one.

Now I restart WSO2 and try again with the same token, getting the expected result of access denied:

```
(900910) - The access token does not allow you to access the requested resource</ams:description></ams:fault>%
```

I have needed to restart the platform so that scope changes are considered!! Is this a bug, a expected behaviour (it shouldn't...) of is there any way to force the refreshment of the endpoint requirements (appart from just publishing the changed API).?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you generate a new access token after either modifying or deleting
>   a scope of an API resource that you had previously invoked, you will
>   not be able to access that particular resource of the API for a period
>   of 15 minutes, which is the default Gateway cache period, because the
>   WSO2 API Manager Gateway is designed to cache the details of the
>   resource on its side.

Ref: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM250/Scope+Management+with+OAuth+Scopes

This is not a practical problem in a typical production environment, as API updates in a production environment are very rare.

However, if this is really a problem for you, you can override the default scope validator[1] by extending it to not to use this cache. This is configured in `identity.xml`.

[1] https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-inbound-auth-oauth/blob/master/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/oauth2/validators/JDBCScopeValidator.java#L92

Comment: @codependent default approach updating API and its scopes in production would be creating a new API version (indeed requiring a new subscription), or just wait until the existing token is expired